# How to generate .47 files from ORCA-5.0.3 ? Also, can we analyze the second order perturbation energy analysis within the nbo scheme using GENNBO?

Tags: orca

I am using ORCA-5.0.3 as ESS package and our group has also recently purchased nbo7 which is not interfaced with the ESS. I had tried multiple ways to generate .47 file but couldn't succeed and am currently using Multiwfn to convert .gbw files to .47 files. I have tried NBO calculation using the files generated but could not find particularly the second order perturbation analysis.

Comment: +1 Welcome to our forum.